# Best Practice for User Registration using PHP + Phonegap

Tags: php, cordova, user-registration

I'm currently developing an application for Android using Phonegap (HTML+JS) and PHP for server platform. And here are my current login process :

- I stored a secret app id (let's call it an app_id) in the javascript which later will be stored on APK file
- Whenever a user want to register from the android application, he/she need to enter for example : email, password, and his/her gender. So the application will send the following data to the server :

  POST https://mywebsite.com/register.php?app_id=[MY_SECRET_APP_ID]&email=[EMAIL_ADDRESS]&password=[PASSWORD]&gender=[GENDER]

I also plan to use https on my website.

My questions are:

Is this secure enough? 
I have a thinking that maybe someone could guess or using specific method to get my MY_SECRET_APP_ID, then he/she can do the "registration spam" to my server.

Are there any reference for registration method using Phonegap?

Thanks for your answer

Comment: General rule: Assume anything on the client-side is insecure

Comment: @JamieTaylor even if the HTML+JS packed in APK file? Is there known method to unpack the APK file and get the source code of the application maybe?

Comment: Maybe, but it would be easier for someone on the same network to just load up [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and wait for the POST request. You have stated however that you're using HTTPS, I'd still not trust the client with my keys though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider that every APK can be unpacked, and so readable!
in more of that, if you don't use SSL, all your request can be sniffed (like Jamie says)

try to make a code changing in the time, like a reverse encryptionable string, time based.

Comment: Actually yes,  I just found a way to unpack the apk and retrieve the html+js content in the apk...